# IE not show newest data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use AngularJS to get data from server. It work well in chrome and firefox if data in server changed. But in IE, It does not show the newest data. I think because IE save data in cache so I send request to server to get new data but IE still shows old data.
How to fix this bug.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this: https://github.com/saintmac/angular-cache-buster
It adds a query string to the requests like `?timestamp=123456789` to disallow IE to cache it.

Basically if you don't want to use that, you have just to add a different query string to the url requested each time. This prevents IE from caching the request.

Answer (score 0):

IE caches the call, and if you are going to send the same call, then IE will return the cached data.

If you are using $http for your calls, then you can simply add the following code in config function

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate';
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Pragma'] = 'no-cache';
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["If-Modified-Since"] = "0";
```

However, if you are using jQuery or even $http (another solution), add timestamp in the call along with existing parameters.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "your_url",
    data: {
        param1 : value1 , 
        timestamp : new Date().getTime()
    },
    success: successCallbackFn
});
```